# Virtual printer redirected to real printer but with certain options set

Tags: printing

How can I, in Windows 7, set up a virtual printer that's just an alias to another printer I have installed, but with certain options set? I'd like to make the virtual printer redirect to a certain network printer but with output going to the manual feed tray. (Some new software I just started using just sends the job right to the printer without going through the dialog that would allow me to choose the manual feed tray.)

Comment: Perhaps you can simply install the printer again and set some specific defaults for that instance? Try out this answer here: http://superuser.com/a/260035/128359

Comment: Thanks; perhaps this should be closed as a duplicate then. However, I tried the method given there except adjusted for a network printer (the answer only addresses local printers -- but a comment says it works for network), but no new printer was set up. I hope someone on that question can fill me in.