# How can I make a copy of a Networked printer in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, printing

Having upgraded from Windows 7 to 10, one feature I am looking for is having multiple copies of a networked printer, each with different settings, as I did in Windows 7, as described in this question,

[How can I make a copy of a printer in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/250417/how-can-i-make-a-copy-of-a-printer-in-windows-7#)

Has anyone figured out how to do this in Windows 10? The same process does not seem to work for me.