# Duplicate a network-shared printer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, network-printer

I'm trying to set up an automated print system and would benefit from having the same network-shared printer installed in multiple copies, each with different default settings (colour vs B&W, dual-sided vs one-sided, etc), then my printing process could pick the printer needed rather than worry about setting these parameters in-code.

I know it's possible to install a duplicate of a local or network printer as answered in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/250417/how-can-i-make-a-copy-of-a-printer-in-windows-7) question. However, network-shared printers don't follow the same rule and while they DO have a port specified, that port isn't available when attempting to create a duplicate.

Is it possible to create a duplicate of a network-shared printer?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, you could create TCP/IP printer ports with VBscript. I have not had the opportunity to test whether it still works the same in Windows 10.

This is the (somewhat simplified) add-tcp-ip-port.vbs script I used:

```vb
ip = args.Item(0)

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set objNewPort = objWMIService.Get("Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort").SpawnInstance_

objNewPort.Name = "IP_" & ip
objNewPort.Protocol = 1
objNewPort.HostAddress = ip
objNewPort.PortNumber = "9100"
objNewPort.SNMPEnabled = False
objNewPort.Put_

MsgBox "OK. Added port at " & ip, vbOK, "Creating JetDirect TCP/IP port"
```

An example script which used this to install a printer looked like this:

```
@echo off

echo Installing NRG MP C4501 Copier bw

SET IP=192.168.44.19
SET NAME=Copier black-white
SET DRIVER=NRG MP 4500 PCL 6
SET INF=\\SomeServer\install\drivers\NRG-MP-C4501-Copier\MP4500-black-white\oemsetup.inf

echo Create TCP/IP port %IP% ...
wscript "%~dp0add-tcp-ip-port.vbs" %IP%

echo Installing "%NAME%" using "%DRIVER%" driver from "%INF%" ...

rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /m "%DRIVER%" /ia /f "%INF%" /u
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /m "%DRIVER%" /b "%NAME%" /if /f "%INF%" /r "IP_%IP%" /u /z
```